# Another issue in Discord Bot Reminder command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

recently I've made a discord bot reminder command and got an issue with it, but thanks to Nurqm's help I was able to fix it.
However, I got another issue in the time setting, when I do `/reminder 5days Fix the server`, which is a reminder to remind me to fix the server after 5 days, I get a ValueError.

This is my code:

```
@client.command(case_insensitive = True, aliases = ["remind", "remindme", "remind_me"])
@commands.bot_has_permissions(attach_files = True, embed_links = True)
async def reminder(ctx, time, *, reminder):
    print(time)
    print(reminder)
    user = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{client.user.avatar_url}")
    seconds = 0
    if reminder is None:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning', value='Please specify what do you want me to remind you about.') # Error message
    if time.lower().endswith("days"):
        seconds += int(time[:-4]) * 60 * 60 * 24
        counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60 // 24} days"
    if time.lower().endswith("h"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60
        counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60} hours"
    elif time.lower().endswith("m"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60
        counter = f"{seconds // 60} minutes"
    elif time.lower().endswith("s"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1])
        counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
    if seconds == 0:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                        value='Please specify a proper duration, send reminder_help for more information.')
    elif seconds < 300:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                        value='You have specified a too short duration!\nMinimum duration is 5 minutes.')
    elif seconds > 7776000:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning', value='You have specified a too long duration!\nMaximum duration is 90 days.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Alright, I will remind you about {reminder} in {counter}.")
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        await ctx.send(f"Hi, you asked me to remind you about {reminder} {counter} ago.")
        return
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error is: `Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5day'`

If anyone knows any information about how to deal with this error please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured why that doesn't work, because you create a `if statement` every time so when you type `/reminder 10days test`, it triggers days but also triggers `elif time.lower().endswith("s"):`. If you change this `if time.lower().endswith("h"):` `if statement` to `elif statement`, your problem will be solved.

Comment: That is indeed the correct solution, I also added every possible alias of the time like min, hr, sec, etc.. So I had to rearrange the order of the if statements, putting the "s" and "d" statements last. Thank you for your continued help.